# Perform rounding on integral type, but not fractional type

Tags: c++, templates, types

In the following function I am looking for an expression to replace `isIntegral<T>`.

The intention is that when `T` is an integral type we add `0.5f` before `static_cast` implictly floors the value (and so we obtain a rounded value), but when `T` is a fractional type we add nothing, and so the `static_cast` can only reduce the precision.

```
T interpolate( T const & prev, T const & next, float interpolation )
{
    float prevFloat = static_cast< float >( prev );
    float nextFloat = static_cast< float >( next );

    float result = prevFloat + ( (nextFloat-prevFloat) * interpolation );

    return static_cast< T >( result + ( isIntegral<T> ? 0.5f : 0.0f );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer` (it's in the `<limits>` header).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just declare `const float addend = 0.5f - static_cast<T>(0.5f)`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::is_integral<T>::value
```

If you include `<type_traits>`, most compilers support this now.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible (without any runtime overhead) with some Boost magic (not tested):

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type
interpolate(const T& prev, const T& next, float interpolation) {
    // code for the case that T is an integral type
}
template<typename T>
typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type
interpolate(const T& prev, const T& next, float interpolation) {
    // code for the case that T is not an integral type
}
```

Comment: In practice, the compiler should optimise the ternary expression (in the OP's code) away to nothing via constant-folding.

Comment: Correct, using `enable_if` is probably overhead here. It is nevertheless useful if the codes for different types vastly differ.